# Pie chart doesn't render completely

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules, vue-chartjs

I created a repro example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-fordd).
As you can see the legenda is rendered but the graph isn't. What is causing this undesirable behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters you pass to `dataStatusWa` are in the opposite order.
Try changing (in App.vue):

```
dataStatusWa() {
      return dataStatusWa(this.getStatusWa, this.getStatusWaLabel);
}
```

to:

```
dataStatusWa() {
      return dataStatusWa(this.getStatusWaLabel, this.getStatusWa);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. been coding for 8 hours straight, got unconsciously misplaced it.

Answer (score 0):

I'have modified the code to bind a sample data
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-p33n7

To show the chart you should have an object with the following structure ( labels, backgroundcolor and data should of the same length)

```js
{
  labels: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"],
  datasets: [
              {
                label: "Data One",
                backgroundColor: ["#41B883", "#E46651", "#00D8FF"],
                data: [1, 10, 5]
              }
     ]
  }
```

Correct the response what you are getting from service. Let me know if you need help to do that.

Comment: That is what he is returning in `util.js`. The problem is that he is passing the parameters in the wrong order. See my answer.

Comment: Yup. You are right.